# CASE statement for date comparison within WHERE clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I am working with a query which contains CASE statement within WHERE clause inside which I have to compare date column with 2 variables fromDate and toDate if it is not null. But SQL Server 2008 is giving some errors like “Incorrect syntax near '>'” while executing it. Can anyone please help me with the correct query? Here is the query:

```
declare 
@fromDate varchar(32)= '2015-08-04',
@toDate varchar(32) = '2016-01-04'

SELECT 
DC_MASTER.DC_NO,
PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME,
CUS_NAME  
FROM DC_ITEM
INNER JOIN DC_MASTER ON DC_MASTER.DC_NO=DC_ITEM.DC_NO  
INNER JOIN ITEM_MASTER ON item_master.ITEM_CODE  = DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE  
INNER JOIN  CUSTOMER_MASTER ON customer_master.CUS_CODE = DC_MASTER.CUS_CODE 
INNER JOIN LOCATION_MASTER ON location_master.LOC_CODE  = DC_ITEM.LOC_CODE 
WHERE DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE=item_master.ITEM_CODE 
AND CASE 
WHEN @fromDate IS NOT NULL AND @toDate IS NOT NULL THEN DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME >= @fromDate and PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME <= @toDate
END
```

Comment: That's a case expression (returns a value), not a case statement (conditional execution of code).

Comment: Can you give me the correct way of using case. Actually, I need to get records between those 2 date if it is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily turn it into a normal where condition instead of case :

```
declare 
@fromDate varchar(32)= '2015-08-04',
@toDate varchar(32) = '2016-01-04'

SELECT 
DC_MASTER.DC_NO,
PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME,
CUS_NAME  
FROM DC_ITEM
INNER JOIN DC_MASTER ON DC_MASTER.DC_NO=DC_ITEM.DC_NO  
INNER JOIN ITEM_MASTER ON item_master.ITEM_CODE  = DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE  
INNER JOIN  CUSTOMER_MASTER ON customer_master.CUS_CODE = DC_MASTER.CUS_CODE 
INNER JOIN LOCATION_MASTER ON location_master.LOC_CODE  = DC_ITEM.LOC_CODE 
WHERE DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE=item_master.ITEM_CODE 
AND ((@fromDate IS NOT NULL AND @toDate IS NOT NULL and DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME >= @fromDate
and PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME <= @toDate) or @fromDate IS NULL or @toDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the logic to:

```
WHERE DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE=item_master.ITEM_CODE 
AND (@fromDate IS NULL OR @toDate IS NULL
     OR (DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME >= @fromDate 
         and PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME <= @toDate)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

A case *expression* isn't required.

Note, is either parameter is null the the date range will not work, so my presumption is that if either are NULL then you want all rows.

```
SELECT
      DC_MASTER.DC_NO
    , PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME
    , CUS_NAME
FROM DC_ITEM
      INNER JOIN DC_MASTER ON DC_MASTER.DC_NO = DC_ITEM.DC_NO
      INNER JOIN ITEM_MASTER ON item_master.ITEM_CODE = DC_ITEM.ITEM_CODE
      INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_MASTER ON customer_master.CUS_CODE = DC_MASTER.CUS_CODE
      INNER JOIN LOCATION_MASTER ON location_master.LOC_CODE = DC_ITEM.LOC_CODE
WHERE (DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME >= @fromDate
      AND PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME <= @toDate
      )
      OR (@fromDate IS NULL OR @toDate IS NULL)
```

[edit]
By the way, best practice for date ranges is to use >= and then <

- see: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-2 (Itzik Ben-Gan)

When you use >= and then <= you have exactly the same issues that **between** causes.